# Is it possible to use EPS file (created with eps2write) in EndPage procedure?

Tags: ghostscript, eps

For testing purposes, let's draw some meaningless rectangles:

```
gswin32c -q -o f.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -c "<</PageSize[595 842]>>setpagedevice 0 0 595 842 rectfill showpage"
```

+

```
gswin32c -q -o f.eps -sDEVICE=eps2write -f f.pdf
```

And ps.ps file:

```
<<
    /EndPage {
        exch pop 
        2 ne dup {
            1 dict begin
            /showpage {} def
            (f.eps) run
            end
        } if
    }
>> setpagedevice
```

And then

```
gswin32c -q -o out.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -f ps.ps -f f.pdf
```

produces an error:

> %%[ Error handled by opdfread.ps : GPL Ghostscript 9.15: Unrecoverable
>   error, exit code 1 Unrecoverable error: typecheck in if Operand stack:
>       typecheck    ebuf  false  false  --nostringval--

On the other hand, if I create EPS with another tool, e.g. `xpdf`'s `pdftops`:

```
pdftops -eps f.pdf f.eps
```

... then EPS can be placed as e.g. watermark or logo with above command:

```
gswin32c -q -o out.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -f ps.ps -f f.pdf
```

So the question is, is it possible to use Ghostscript's `eps2write` for the purpose, maybe I'm missing something.

I tried to bracket `(f.eps) run` with calls to `BeginEPSF` and `EndEPSF` as defined in Adobe's **EPSF Format Specification**, but it didn't help. And after decoding prologue which `eps2write` creates (which, itself, gives same error if run from `EndPage`), it looks to me that it violates section on *Illegal and Restricted Operators* of mentioned Specification.

**Edit:**
I think there's an issue with the *Immediately Evaluated Names* if code is run from `EndPage`. In prologue, which `eps2write` creates, there's a fragment not very far from the beginning:

```
//SetPageSize{
//RotatePages//FitPages or//CenterPages or{
mark(/RotatePages, /FitPages and CenterPages are not allowed with /SetPageSize)//error exec
}if
}
{
//FitPages//CenterPages and{
mark(CenterPages is not allowed with /FitPages)//error exec
}if
}
ifelse
```

If I frame it like this:

```
SetPageSize ==
//SetPageSize ==
{

//SetPageSize{
//RotatePages//FitPages or//CenterPages or{
mark(/RotatePages, /FitPages and CenterPages are not allowed with /SetPageSize)//error exec
}if
}
{
//FitPages//CenterPages and{
mark(CenterPages is not allowed with /FitPages)//error exec
}if
}
ifelse

} stopped { (***\n) print } if
```

And modify `ps.ps` slightly:

```
<<
    /EndPage {
        exch pop 
        2 ne dup {
            1 dict begin
            /showpage {} def
            (prologue.ps) run
            end
        } if
    }
>> setpagedevice
```

Then this command:

```
gswin32c -q -o out.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -f ps.ps -f f.pdf
```

...gives this output:

```
false 
/SetPageSize
*** 
%%[ Error handled by opdfread.ps : GPL Ghostscript 9.14: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

I.e. it fails in above fragment (and for obvious reason, I think) and then fails somewhere else further down within `prologue.ps`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you think is violating the restricted operstors please ? ie what operstor is used ?

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to think about that a bit......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so I did something similar to your expereience. I started with a simple PostScript file (testeps.ps):

```
%!
0 1 0 setrgbcolor
0 0 100 100 rectfill
showpage
```

I then ran that through Ghostscript using the eps2write device:

```
./gs -sDEVICE=eps2write -sOutputFile=out.eps -dCompressPages=false testeps.ps
```

I then constructed another test file (test.ps):

```
%!

<<
    /EndPage {
        exch pop 
        2 ne dup {
            1 dict begin
            /showpage {} def
            (/temp/out.eps) run
            end
        } if
    }
>> setpagedevice

1 0 0 setrgbcolor
0 100 100 100 rectfill

showpage
```

and ran that through GS:

```
./gs test.ps
```

The file ran to completion, and contained appropriately coloured rectangles at the correct positions on the page.

[image: full page A4 PNG output]

Its possible this is something which has been fixed (you don't say what version of Ghostscript you are using). The next release (9.16) is due very shortly, or you can build iot yourself from source, I'd suggest you try it when its available.

Comment: The idea was to 'stamp' an existing multipage **PDF** with a 'stamp' (e.g. logo) that contains nothing but call to `setpagedevice` (plus external EPS). Then command **fails** as I described (GS versions 9.14, 9.15). But, as I found now, looking at your example, command does **not** fail if we stamp **postscript** file (as opposed to stamping PDF). So there's an easy workaround, I should have checked it before posting this question. And, I have another little issue, this time with using `BeginPage`, maybe it will better be another question, though I'll do some more checks before posting :)

Comment: The Ghostscript PDF interpreter does tricky stuff, I'm not sure I would rely on the behaviour of BeginPage and EndPage with it, though it does work 'usually'....